# Binding 2 ObservableCollections to Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, observablecollection

I'm new to WPF, and having trouble with the binding, have been searching for difference solutions, but nothing have helped.
Got 2 Observable Collections, I want to be binded into to different columns of a listview.
XAML code:

```
<GroupBox Header="Search results" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="727" Width="739" FontFamily="Malgun Gothic" FontSize="24">
        <ListView x:Name="ListView1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="729" FontFamily="Malgun Gothic" FontSize="24" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="0,0,-2,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Search, Path=Library}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Song name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Track}" Width="550"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Artist" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}" Width="170"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.DataContext>
                <Classes:Library/>
            </ListView.DataContext>
            <Classes:Library Text=""/>
        </ListView>
    </GroupBox>
```

From xaml.cs

```
    Library CallSearch = new Library();
    Playlist Songs = new Playlist();
    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            CallSearch.Text = textSearch.Text;
            CallSearch.Search();
    }
```

From Class:

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> track = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private ObservableCollection<string> artist = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Track
    {
        get { return track; }
        set { track = value; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Artist
    {
        get { return artist; }
        set { artist = value; }
    }
```

Inside a public void:

```
            foreach (DirectoryInfo diNext in dirs)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo test in diNext.GetFileSystemInfos("*"+tb+"*"+".mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    u.Read(test.FullName);
                    Track.Add(u.Title);
                    Artist.Add(u.Artist);
                }
            }
```

What I'm missing?

UPDATE FOR NIT:
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Albums' property not found on 'object' ''Library' (HashCode=36404074)'. BindingExpression:Path=Albums; DataItem='Library' (HashCode=36404074); target element is 'ListView' (Name='ListView1'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Track' property not found on 'object' ''Library' (HashCode=40706798)'. BindingExpression:Path=Track; DataItem='Library' (HashCode=40706798); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Artist' property not found on 'object' ''Library' (HashCode=40706798)'. BindingExpression:Path=Artist; DataItem='Library' (HashCode=40706798); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: It is NOT a property without a get http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having two disjointed collections, create a model class containing two properties

```
public class Album
{
 public string Track{get;set;}
 public string Artist{get;set;}
}
```

and create the ObservableCollection of this class

```
public ObservableCollection<Album> Albums{get;set;}

foreach (DirectoryInfo diNext in dirs)
{
      foreach (FileInfo test in diNext.GetFileSystemInfos("*"+tb+"*"+".mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
      {
                    u.Read(test.FullName);
                    Album album = new Album;
                    album.Track = u.Title;
                    album.Artist = u.Artist;
                    Albums.Add(album);
       }
 }
```

Now bind this Collection to ListView

```
  <ListView x:Name="ListView1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="729" FontFamily="Malgun Gothic" FontSize="24" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="0,0,-2,0" ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=Albums}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Song name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Track}" Width="550"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Artist" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}" Width="170"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.DataContext>
            <Classes:Library/>
        </ListView.DataContext>
        <Classes:Library Text=""/>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: The code builds but nothing have changes besides it really cleans up the code :) thx for that.

But It still dosent show anything. Have debugged and checked the new Collection isnt empty

Comment: Albums needs to be public property (get)

Comment: Dosent know what you mean? It is public?

Comment: Albums should be a property in Library.. not variable..pls see the updated answer

Comment: Sorry for bust your balls with being noobish.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object keeps happening at Albums.Add(album) ?

Comment: you have to initialize it in your constructor or someplace before using it